# curl getting contents of page before submitting

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to access my account for a site I am registered to using curl, the problem is that the login page has a hidden authentication input field e.g. `<input type='hidden' name='auth' value='adih2yerjh'/>`, is there a way to make sure that I check the site for this field using curl before submitting a form? here is a mock up of my function

```
function login(){
    $login_email = 'email';
    $login_pass = 'password';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.mysite.com/login.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'email='.urlencode($login_email).'&pass='.urlencode($login_pass).'&login=Login');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
    $page = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $page;
}
```

**Edit**: The auth code changes on every page load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
$url = "http://www.mysite.com/login.php";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match("~<input type='hidden' name='auth'  value='(.*?)' />~",$html,$authHidden);

/**
 // Run your post request with auth=$authHidden
 */
```

Comment: this would not work because the auth code changes on ever page visit, I would have to do this in 1 go

Comment: Oh wait I see your reasoning, im sure If I have not submitted the form the auth code would still be valid

Comment: @mk_89 you are not submitting ... The session should still be active .. morover am working on limited information provided by you .. and nothing talks about changing codes

Answer (score 1):

You have to make two curl requests.
First get the page content and try to extract that name from the HTML. You may also need to handle with sessions or cookies.
Then you can make the second curl request to submit.